# Swift equivalent "?:"

Tags: swift

**ObjC**

```
[MyObject doThisWithString:string?: [MyObject otherString]];
```

How can I do this in Swift?

```
extension MyObject {
    func doThisWithString(string: String?) {
        ... <- assume defined
    }

    func otherString() -> String {
        return ... <- assume defined
    }
}

var MyInstance: MyObject
...
MyInstance.doThisWithString(myStringVar?: MyInstance.otherString()) <- how do I do this?
```

Comment: The `?:` operator is shorthand syntax for a ternary. The full syntax would be `string ? string : [MyObject otherString]`.

Comment: check this doc...http://nshipster.com/swift-operators/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a '??' operator called as 'Nil coalescing' operator. It does the exact thing you need. To quote [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

> Nil Coalescing Operator
>
> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The
>   expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must
>   match the type that is stored inside a.
>
> The nil coalescing operator is shorthand for the code below:
>
> a != nil ? a! : b

In your case, you can write your expression as:

```
MyInstance.doThisWithString(myStringVar ?? MyInstance.otherString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift provides a very simple solution to this. **Nil Coalescing Operator** or **??**

Nil Coalescing Operator basically tries to provide some default value to the optional so that you don't have to forcefully unwrap the optional.

For eg: var someValue = someOptional ?? DEFAULT_VALUE(default value depends upon the type of optional.)

In case of instances you can simply replace the DEFAULT_VALUE with the Class's default instance.

For eg: In case of *cellForRowAtIndexPath*, it requires you to forcefully unwrap the cell you've created but you can use Nil Coalescing Operator there as well as  **return someCell ?? TableViewCellClass()**